# python: import function doesnt work in 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.5, python-importlib, imp

I use this to import a function in 2.7 which works:

```
def import_x():
    import os
    import imp
    directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    os.environ['__PYTHON_SYS_PATH_FOR_TESTFOLDER__'] = directory
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('test', [ directory ])
    if fp is not None:
        try:
            x = imp.load_module('test', fp, os.path.realpath(pathname), description)
        finally:
            fp.close()
        return x

test = import_x()
```

But I struggle to make this work in 3.5. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
import sys
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
```

I'm not sure about the specific change, but this seems to work.